# Refusing new connections without closing current connections

Tags: java, serversocket

I have a daemon that is designed to accept connections from devices out in the field--they do some custom communication using commands/responses.

Every time a device connects to the port, we spawn a thread to handle that communication.  Each thread stops itself and gets destroyed when the communication is over.  Communication may last anywhere from a few seconds to a few minutes.  The spawning of these threads is done in a never ending while-loop which creates a new instance of our Thread class that blocks on waiting to accept() a connection to the port, when a connection is made the thread is spawned, the loop goes back around to start another thread spawn and accept().

When the number of possible simultaneous connections was relatively small this was acceptable--but we now have tens of thousands of devices out there that may all be trying to communicate at the same time (a worst case situation for sure, but still possible).

We'd like to refuse new connections once we pass a certain value of Thread.activeCount() -- As in, from an outside point of view trying to open a socket connection would simply fail as through the port were not open, connection refused.

The code below a highly simplified snippet of what I was hoping might work, but what actually occurs is that we still accept new connections from the outside, they just don't get attached to a thread until the activeCount drops and the connections are passed to new threads.

```
while (1)
{
    if (Thread.activeCount() < maxThreads)
    {
        new MyCustomThread(serverSocket.accept(), dataSource).start();
    }
}
```

Is there some way that when my activeCount exceeds a certain value, I could close the port temporarily and therefore reject new connections without killing any that are already in progress?

Comment: To me, it looks like you need a fixed pool of threads. I would suggest you to go through "Executor Service" in Java. That would help you in the current use case.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful I guess the point is not to make clients wait for connection to establish or step into any queue but rather to force them fail to connect.

Comment: Probably the solution is to accept the connection, then check if the limit reached in your MyCustomThread and close the given socket if true with no any handling.

Comment: E.g.  serverSocket.accept().close();